Ruby Eval explaning the evaluated result
I have an app where XL like formulas are stored in the DB, and we use eval to get the results from the formula. e.x formula = "a + b - c", and we do eval(formula), and this works.
Now we want to be able to also print out the formula with the values used, so the user can have an explanation of how the formulas results are computed. So if a=3, b=2, c=1, then eval(formula) = 4. but we also want to display the string "3 + 2 - 1".
Note a,b,c are not simple numbers and can be complex expressions. How to approach this?
Some examples of formulas I have are

capital_commitment.committed_amount_cents * ( fund_unit_setting.management_fee * ( ( @end_date - @start_date ).to_i + 1 ) / 365 ) / 100

AccountEntry.total_amount(capital_commitment.account_entries, name: 'Cost Of Exited Investments', end_date: @end_date)

( capital_commitment.unit_type && capital_commitment.unit_type == 'Series C' ) ? 0 : ( ( @current_portfolio_fmv + @distributions - @remittances ) * 0.2 )


#########################
Finally solved it like this
  def parse_statement(binding)
  statement = formula
  buffer = Parser::Source::Buffer.new('(string)')
  buffer.source = statement
  ast = Parser::CurrentRuby.new.parse(buffer)

  expressions = []
  find_expressions(ast, expressions)
  expression_map = {}
  expressions.each do |exp|
    val = eval(exp, binding)
    expression_map[exp] = val unless (val.is_a?(ApplicationRecord) || val.is_a?(OpenStruct))
  end
  expression_map
end

  def find_expressions(node, expressions)
  case node.type
  when :send
    expressions << node.loc.expression.source
  when :lvar, :ivar, :const
    expressions << node.loc.name.source
  when :str
    expressions << node.loc.expression.source
  end

  node.children.each do |child|
    find_expressions(child, expressions) if child.is_a?(Parser::AST::Node)
  end
end

Hope this helps others who follow

Can you provide an example of how you are setting a,b, and c now for the purposes of eval? Can you also provide a complex example? Chances are you will need to build a parser to extract a, b, and c and then use a binding context to substitute each variable with its value but we need a few more details.

Very dangerous for production. You should strictly validate params to avoid puts rm -rf /, or puts cat config/master.key or similar XL like formulas:)

Ive added examples into the question above. I tried to use regex to extract the variables from the statement, but that approach does not work where method calls are involved. Lets ignore security for a minute

You should write your solution as an answer and then accept it.

I agree with the comments that this might be dangerous in production, perhaps something like Dentaku can help you. We use it to evaluate formulas stored in the DB and it has a feature that allows you to show intermediate values for a certain formula (FlatHash). Here is a guide that might help you getting started with it!
